# Grouby function creating 2 new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the 'Materiais' column that indicates the code of the product, the 'Values' Column, that corresponds to the product values, and 'Month' columns that corresponds to it months.

```
        Ano Meses Materiais  Values
112    2018    M1     52793  1700.0
113    2018    M2     52793   900.0
114    2018    M3     52793  1400.0
115    2018    M4     52793   500.0
116    2018    M5     52793   300.0
117    2018    M6     52793   600.0
118    2018    M7     52793  1800.0
119    2018    M8     52793   500.0
256    2018    M1     53201  5300.0
257    2018    M2     53201  1300.0
258    2018    M3     53201  1900.0
259    2018    M4     53201  5400.0
260    2018    M5     53201  2300.0
261    2018    M6     53201  2100.0
262    2018    M7     53201  3000.0
263    2018    M8     53201  1200.0
```

Using these functions:

```
b = df.groupby('Materiais')['Values'].mean()
a = df.groupby('Materiais')['Values'].std()



     Materiais        std
    0       10408   1086.278049
    1       10422   1359.030642
    2        1192    738.241153
    3        1193    402.492236


 Materiais        Mean
0       10408   2300.000000
1       10422   5187.500000
2        1192   1125.000000
3        1193    280.000000
```

I get the mean and standard deviation by product. However, I have to use a merge function to keep both (mean and Standard deviation) on the same dataframe.

Is there a directly way to calculate both (mean and Standard deviation), creating 2 columns on the same dataframe ? Something like:

```
df.groupby('Materiais')['Values'].mean().std()
```

Without having to use a merge function ?

Comment: You can use `.agg` instead... `df.groupby('Meses').Values.agg(['std', 'mean'])`

Comment: it sounds a good option. Thanks